# How to output register value to stdout like :!echo command in vim?

Tags: vim

I have done this:

:reg a

```
"a   iabc
```

I want to output the value in register a like `:w !xargs -n1 echo` command, but not all buffer content just the register value.

Thx in advanced!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
:echo getreg('a')
```

> #### `getreg([{regname} [, 1 [, {list}]]])`
>
> The result is a String, which is the contents of register `{regname}`. Example:
>
> ```
> :let cliptext = getreg('*')
> ```
>
> When `{regname}` was not set the result is an empty string.
>
> `getreg('=')` returns the last evaluated value of the expression register. (For use in maps.) `getreg('=', 1)` returns the expression itself, so that it can be restored with `setreg()`. For other registers the extra argument is ignored, thus you can always give it. If `{list}` is present and TRUE, the result type is changed to List. Each list item is one text line. Use it if you care about zero bytes possibly present inside register: without third argument both NLs and zero bytes are represented as NLs (see NL-used-for-Nul). When the register was not set an empty list is returned. If `{regname}` is not specified, `v:register` is used.

Comment: There is a mistake in my expression. I want to output the register value like `:w !xargs -n1 echo`, but not all buffer content just the register value.

Comment: @BigShield: Do you want to write it to a file, give it as an argument to a command, something else…?

Comment: @BigShield: `:echo system('echo ' . shellescape(getreg('a')))` to pass it as an argument, `:echo system('cat', getreg('a'))` to pass it as input.

Comment: What I need is system command! Thx for your patience to answer!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap in `exe` to use the value of getreg within a vim command:

```
:exe ":!echo ".getreg('a')
```